# .inf file AddRegistry section flag meaning (HKR,,"UpperFilters",0x00010008,"upperfilt" ) what does 0x00010008 stand for?

Tags: windows, registry, driver, inf

At [MSDN Installing a Filter Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547595%28VS.85%29.aspx#ddk_installing_a_class_filter_driver_dg) there is a sample file given (reproduced lower).

In the `[upperfilter_addreg]` section there is the registry line `HKR,,"UpperFilters",0x00010008,"upperfilt"`.

**What is the meaning of the `0x00010008` flag ?**

Note that this file is meant to install an Upper Filter Driver.
Thank you microsoft for your great resourceful complete docs.

```
:
[DestinationDirs]
upperfilter_copyfiles = 12

[upperfilter_inst]
CopyFiles = upperfilter_copyfiles
AddReg = upperfilter_addreg

[upperfilter_copyfiles]
upperfilt.sys

[upperfilter_addreg]
; append this service to existing REG_MULTI_SZ list, if any
HKR,,"UpperFilters",0x00010008,"upperfilt" 

[upperfilter_inst.Services]
AddService = upperfilt,,upperfilter_service

[upperfilter_service]
DisplayName   = %upperfilter_ServiceDesc%
ServiceType   = 1   ; SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
StartType     = 3   ; SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl  = 1   ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
ServiceBinary = %12%\upperfilt.sys
:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the help in the [WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546320(VS.85).aspx).

Should be

```
FLG_ADDREG_TYPE_MULTI_SZ | FLG_ADDREG_APPEND
```

so more its what is supplied in the comment in the line above the AddReg directive itself.